# Exporting a table to pdf with jsPDF

Tags: pdf, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to export a table to PDF, however I get a pdf with all the info displayed as a list, I'd like to have the pdf display the full table as seen on the HTML could someone help me see whats wrong with my code?

```
    function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

        source = $('#customers')[0];

        specialElementHandlers = {

            '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {

                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };

        pdf.fromHTML(
                source, 
                margins.left, 
                margins.top, {
                    'width': margins.width, // 
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                },
        function(dispose) {

            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
        }
        , margins);
    }
```